# Integrebility of a function with a parameter in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

I think I got the hang of proving whether or not a function in 1 variable is integrable. But how would one do this in two variables? Take for example the function
\begin{equation}
f = (0, + \infty) \times (0, + \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f(x,y) = \frac{\exp(-x)\sin(x)}{(1+xy)^{\alpha}}.
\end{equation}
For what values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is this function integrable?

I'm assuming it's not as easy as looking at both variables individually and seeing for what $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the function is integrable, is it?

I'm also curious to any hints for the example. Thanks!

Comment: In general and specifically for this example Tonelli's theorem is useful.

Comment: @shashi I don't think we've covered that theorem in class, so I'm assuming that's not something can use...

Comment: Maybe called it Fubini?

Comment: @Shashi ah yes, swapping the integrals if the function is positive measurable (version 1) or integrable (version 2)

Comment: yes now you can do your thing!

Comment: @Shashi But integrability is a condition for Fubini to hold... Does this mean I have to work backwards in a sense?

Comment: yeah to some extent. You want to show integrability. So you take absolute value of your function which makes it positive. Now Fubini tells you that integration can be done in whatever order you like. Choose your favorite order and try to get some conclusions.

Comment: Thanks! I will try tomorrow and update on how it goes :D

Comment: @Shashi I'm still a bit puzzled on how to proceed... I have made a tiny bit of progress though: $y \mapsto \frac{\exp{(-x)}\sin(x)}{(1+xy)^{\alpha}}$ is in the limit $y \rightarrow 0$ equal to  $\exp{(-x)}\sin(x)$ except when $x \rightarrow \infty$. In the limit $y \rightarrow \infty$ the limit is equal to $0$ except when $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: for fixed $x>0$ you can integrate the function in $y$ on $(0,\infty)$... For which value is such integral convergent? You want to write your integral as $$\iint |f(x, y)|dydx.$$ Do the inner integral and then the outer integral. Check convergence requirements on $\alpha $ at each step.

Comment: @Shashi could you have a look at the answer I posted? thanks!

Comment: The argument seems sound (not sure about the exact evaluation tho)

Comment: @Shashi the evaluation should be ok, I have just omitted some steps

Answer (score 0):

So I have a rough sketch of an answer. Taking the absolute value of the function lets us apply Fubini's theorem to calculate the integrals in whatever order.

First do the integral in the $y$ variable
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(-x) |\sin(x)|}{(1+xy)^{\alpha}}dy = \exp(-x) |\sin(x)| \frac{1}{x(\alpha -1)}
\end{equation}
for all $\alpha > 1$. Now The integral over $x$ is always integrable since $\exp(-x) \sin(x) \frac{1}{x(\alpha -1)} = \Theta(1)$ for $x \rightarrow 0$ and since $\exp(-x)$ goes faster to $0$ than $\frac{1}{x}$ goes to 0 for $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $|\sin x| < 1$.

Could anyone verify this? Have I made any mistakes?